# javascript error being indexed

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a webpage.  On it there is a javascript warning to the users who have javascript disabled.  This is in the body part of the html page, towards the top.  In google this is what shows in the description!

How can I make this go to the bottom of the page to stop google using it as the descriptiuon?

It is in a class if that helps...

Comment: Can you share the source of the page in question?

Comment: The source will be interesting, yes.

Comment: It is text in a div container...that is all...and some text underneath which displays if they do have javascript on.  but google has used the no javascript text...

Comment: Building on things that work ( http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build ) instead of treating people who can't/don't run the JS as second class citizens generally alleviates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move the warning to the bottom of the code you can use absolute positioning (or fixed if you want it to scroll with the page) to have it display at the top of the page.  This way it is not the first text that Google sees when it indexes the page.  Along with that I would add in the meta description tag as Christopher McCann said.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set a meta description tag? Do you have other content on the page?

You can't MAKE google choose what it displays as the description but it will usually use the meta description tag so make sure you have one set. It won't fix straight away - you will need to wait until Google re-crawls your website.